# VBA Listbox and loop

Tags: vba

Im having a trouble understanding For and Do while.

Im trying to put items in a listbox in this order:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

and so on. 
And the same way around

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
```

Up intil 10

How should i attack this issue?

This is what im stuck with:

```
Dim counter1 As Integer 
Dim counter2 As Integer 
 For counter1 = 10 To 1 Step -1 
  For counter2 = 1 To 10 
   ListBox1.Items.Add() 
  Next counter2 
 Next counter1
```

Comment: Two `For` loops (one inside of the other) should work...

Comment: Ive been messing around with two For loops inside of eachother, but cant get it to work as all

Comment: Show what you have tried and we can help figure out the problem.

Comment: `Dim counter1 As Integer
        Dim counter2 As Integer

        For counter1 = 10 To 1 Step -1
            For counter2 = 1 To 10

                ListBox1.Items.Add()


            Next counter2
        Next counter1`

Comment: *Edit your question* to add code - code in comments is difficult to read...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not with using the Loops alone but with using the `ListBox` Methods.
 You can achieve what you want in 2 ways:

1. Initially concatenate (connect) the numbers into a single string and then add it on the Listbox using `AddItem` Method.
2. Populate a multicolumn `ListBox` using a nested loop using `AddItem` and `List` method.

The first one should be something like below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim s As String

    k = 11 ' this determines the exit condition
    For i = 1 To 10
        For j = 1 To 10
            If k = j Then Exit For
            s = IIf(s = "", j, s & " " & j) ' construct the string
        Next
        Me.ListBox1.AddItem s ' add in listbox
        s = ""
        k = k - 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Which will result to:

[image]

**Edit1** No.2 Above

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 10
        .ColumnWidths = "15;15;15;15;15;15;15;15;15;15"
        k = 10 ' determines exit condition
        For i = 1 To 10
            For j = 1 To 10
                If j = 1 Then
                    .AddItem j ' if it is the number 1, use AddItem method
                Else
                    .List(.ListCount - 1, j - 1) = j ' else use the List method
                End If
                If k = j Then Exit For
            Next
            k = k - 1
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

This time, we do not add concatenated numbers into the *ListBox* but we add it 1 by 1 in each row and column of a *multicolumn ListBox*. Result would be:

[image]

I leave the ascending numbers to you. :) I hope this gets you going.